# Are four witnesses needed to convict a slave?

Tags: fiqh, zina, slavery, hudud

> Abd al-Rahman reported that 'Ali, while delivering the address said:
>
> O people, impose the prescribed punishment upon your slaves, those who are married and those not married, for a slave-woman belonging to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) had committed adultery, and he committed me to flog her. But she had recently given birth to a child and I was afraid that if I flogged her I might kill her. So I mentioned that to Allah's Apostle (ﷺ) and he said: You have done well. ([Sahih Muslim 1705](https://sunnah.com/muslim/29/53))

I didn't find any Hadith to establish that we need four witnesses to convict a slave for committing fornication or adultery. The Hadith above is silent on this. Is this requirement sought? Did the Prophet SAW punished the slave after hearing the testimony of four trustworthy witnesses? Or is it reserved only for the free?

Comment: Zina is also proven by confession, and depending on the madhab through evidence such as pregnancy etc. From the context of the above hadith it seems that she was unmarried and gave birth so her Zina is evident.

Comment: What about when his/her master caught him/her committing the act? Is his sole testimony valid? Does he need three other witnesses to make a conviction? Most of the Hadith talk about the free including wives, sons and daughters.

Comment: Sometimes they don't get pregnant. But the master saw her nonetheless.

Comment: Zina requires four (male, trustworthy) testimonies who agree upon having seen "the penetration" any disagreement or doubt would at least lift the punishment. I couldn't make out any difference in this point (amount of necessary witnesses) between free people and slaves. However there's a punishment in the punishment.